On stopping time and filtration containments
This is an attempt to clarify an issue from Section 6 in the proof of Theorem 2.2.
Bass, R. F., Uniqueness in law for pure jump Markov processes, Probab. Theory Relat. Fields 79, No. 2, 271-287 (1988). ZBL0664.60080.
Let $D([0,\infty))$ be the set of all $f : [0,\infty) \to \mathbb R^d$ which are right continuous and possess left sided limits at all points in $[0,\infty)$. For each $t \geq 0$ let $X_t : D([0,\infty)) \to \mathbb R^d$ be given by $X_t(\omega) = \omega(t)$ (coordinate projections). The augmented natural filtration of $\{X_t\}_{t \geq 0}$ will be denoted by $\{\mathcal F_t\}_{t \geq 0}$ with $\mathcal F_{\infty} = \sigma(\cup_{n \geq 1} \mathcal F_n)$. We can define $\mathcal F_{\tau}$ for $\tau$ an a.s. finite stopping time in the usual way.
For $\omega \in D([0,\infty))$ and $\tau$ an a.s. finite stopping time, define $\theta_{\tau} : D([0,\infty)) \to D([0,\infty))$ by $(\theta_{\tau}(\omega))(t) = \omega(t + \tau(\omega))$. (So this is a "random shift" by the stopping time $\tau$).
Now, given $A \in \mathcal{F}_{\tau}$ and $B \in \mathcal F_{\infty}$, let $E_{A,B}$ be the event given by $E_{A,B} = A \cap \{\omega : \theta_{\tau}(\omega) \in B\}$.

Question : Is $\mathcal F_{\infty} = \sigma(\{E_{A,B} : A \in \mathcal{F}_{\tau}, B \in \mathcal F_{\infty}\})$?

According to Bass, this is true!

Intuitively, it does seem to be true. What does it mean to belong to some $E_{A,B}$? The point is, $A \in \mathcal F_{\tau}$ means that membership in $A$ is determined by the values in the collection $\{X_t\}_{0 \leq t \leq \tau}$. On the other hand, $\{\omega : \theta_{\tau}(\omega) \in B\}$ is a set in which membership is determined purely by the values in the collection $\{X_t\}_{t \geq \tau}$.
Thus, effectively, $E_{A,B}$ is an event which is determined by two separate conditions, one applying purely for $\{X_t\}_{0 \leq t \leq \tau}$ and the other purely applying for $\{X_t\}_{t \geq \tau}$.
This leads me to believe that I can use the following steps :

A function $f : D([0,\infty)) \to \mathbb R$ is measurable with respect to $\sigma(\{E_{A,B} : A \in \mathcal{F}_{\tau}, B \in \mathcal F_{\infty}\})$ if and only if it's an a.e. limit of functions of the form $F(\omega) = f_1(\omega)f_2(\theta_{\tau} \circ \omega)$ where $f_1$ depends only on the first "$\tau$" coordinates of $\omega$ and $f_2$ is arbitrary and measurable, and the set of finite sums/products of such functions.

Every function measurable with respect to $\mathcal F_{\infty}$ (one can reduce this to just being measurable with respect to some $\mathcal F_{n}$) can be approximated arbitrarily by finite sums/products of functions of the form $F(\omega)$, $\omega$ described as above.


This way, the set of measurable functions becomes the same for both collections and we're done. However, neither step is particularly clear to me.
-The first isn't because I'm not able to make "first $\tau$ coordinates" rigorous in my working.

For the second, it's known that if $f : \Omega_1 \times \Omega_2 \to \mathbb R$ is a measurable function ($\Omega_1,\Omega_2$ some good enough measurable spaces) then you can approximate it arbitrarily by sums and products of functions of the form $g(x)h(y)$, $g : \Omega_1 \to \mathbb R$ and $h : \Omega_2 \to \mathbb R$ arbitrary measurable. However, in this case, we want $\Omega_1$ to be "the first $\tau$ coordinates" so $\Omega_1$ is varying with the sample, creating problems for me.


I'd appreciate a proof that uses these steps, although I'm assuming there should be one using the $\pi$-$\lambda$ or monotone class theorem or something that I'm also very happy to go with.
